# Cropperjs not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, external-dependencies

I am trying to use the cropperjs library in an Angular project. The cropper example from the documentation works fine on a normal static web page (simple index.html with `<script>` tag for the js and a link to the cropper.css file).

But for some reason this does not work.
Cropper seems to load (`console.log(Cropper)` does the the function), and there is some functionality, but it looks like the style is missing.

`cropper.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

var foo = require('cropperjs/dist/cropper');


@Component({
  selector: "cropper",
  template: `
    <div>
      <img id="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vyeh3vqc93hbye4/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202016-05-27%2017.14.53.png?dl=0">
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['../styles/cropper.css', '../styles/cropper.component.css']
})
export class CropperComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(){
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      crop: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.x);
        console.log(e.detail.y);
        console.log(e.detail.width);
        console.log(e.detail.height);
        console.log(e.detail.rotate);
        console.log(e.detail.scaleX);
        console.log(e.detail.scaleY);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in developers tools, the tags added by cropper.js did not have add the custom attributes Angular uses for styling (the ones that look like `_ngcontent-xpk-4`), so the cropperjs styling did not work.

Just adding the cropper.css (`<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../cropper.css">`) in index.html instead of referring to it in the component solved it.